# grep -E Regex: odd numbers always occur in pairs

Tags: regex, grep

I am trying to find an regex in egrep that shows all lines where the odd numbers occur in pairs

```
666222448999933 <= match
66667774444 <= no match
```

i know a regex to do this but it is quite long because it handles every odd number seperately. So i have to find something like:

```
egrep -v '[^\2]*(([13579])\2)*\2[^\2]'
```

but that won't work

Comment: So what is your question? _I need to find something like ... but I know it won't work_?

Comment: What about your solution doesn't work? And do you want to match pairs that occur in longer runs like '555'? What about multiple pairs like '555555'?

Comment: well the point is that it would be easy if i could backreference like that using egrep. it would have to match 225555555577666633 but not 2255544, cause thats one pair and one single. It also shouldn't match 5579 cause the odd numbers can only pair with an equal number. I know that i can specify a regex for every odd number seperately like this 
$ egrep -v '([^1]1(11)*[^1] | ... | ... | ... | ... )'
But i'd like to know if there is a shorter method. Sorry for the poorly posed question.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do what you want:

```
^[^13579]*(?:([13579])\1[^13579]*)+$
```

It allows any number of leading characters that aren't odd digits, then requires pairs of odd digits, separated by 0 or more other characters.

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/oT0rM4/1)

Answer (score 0):

This is not `grep` nor `regex`, but it solve the problem using `awk`

```
awk -vFS= '{f=$1;for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) {if (f~/[13579]/ && f!=$i && $i~/[13579]/) t=1;f=$i}} t {print;t=0}' file
666222448999933
```

It prints all line where there two neighbor number is odd and not equal, eks `9` and `3`